# Meanjs and angular-bootstrap compatibility issue

Tags: meanjs, angular-bootstrap

I'm trying to run some default examples provided from https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/ with my default Meanjs 0.4.1. Everything is supposed to work properly because the required packages are installed and configured as well. But don't know why, it doesn't. I decided to upgrade to the angular-bootstrap ~0.14 and replace the ~0.13 and now everything works properly. Can somebody be able to tell me what's wrong? Looks like Meanjs team didn't test the installation? I can't believe it so this is why I'm asking you why? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

in ~0.14 the directives of angular bootstrap have a prefix (uib) before the name of the directive, probably you tried the code from the home page of angular-ui that use the prefix instead of the old version of the directive, see the differences in the next example:

New directvies 14.x

```
<uib-accordion></uib-accordion>
```

Older directives 13.x

```
<accordion></accordion>
```

so it's not an error from MeanJs.